i want to display old orders first from orders table based one company and followed by another company like wise
+----------+------------+
|       id |       name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |   storeone | 
|        2 |   storetwo | 
|        3 |  storethree| 
+----------+------------+



+----------+------------+------------+
|       id |    storeid | date       | 
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |          1 | 2024-07-01 | 
|        2 |          2 | 2024-06-01 | 
|        3 |          3 | 2024-07-22 | 
|        4 |          2 | 2024-06-11 | 
|        5 |          3 | 2024-06-14 | 
+----------+------------+------------+

i have used the following query
SELECT `o`.*,`s`.`name` FROM `orders` as o LEFT JOIN `stores` as s
    ON s.id = o.storeid ORDER BY o.date,s.id;

am getting the following result
+----------+------------+------------+-------------
|       id |    storeid | date       | name
+----------+------------+------------+-------------
|        2 |          2 | 2024-06-01 | storetwo   |
|        4 |          2 | 2024-06-11 | storetwo   |
|        5 |          3 | 2024-06-14 | storethree |
|        1 |          1 | 2024-07-01 | storeone   |
|        3 |          3 | 2024-07-22 | storethree |
+----------+------------+------------+-------------

but i want like this
+----------+------------+------------+-------------
|       id |    storeid | date       | name
+----------+------------+------------+-------------
|        2 |          2 | 2024-06-01 | storetwo   |
|        4 |          2 | 2024-06-11 | storetwo   |
|        5 |          3 | 2024-06-14 | storethree |
|        1 |          1 | 2024-07-22 | storethree |
|        3 |          3 | 2024-07-01 | storeone |
+----------+------------+------------+-------------


So you want to order by stored ID first, and by date second?

Is there any rule that defines the order of rows? How is this problem related to PHP?

not order by ID, for example 2024-06-01 is the least date so it should display all the records of storetwo, then 2024-06-14 is the least date so it should display all the records of storethree like that i want

Your "I want like this" data doesn't match the original data. The last two rows have the storeid in the wrong place I think, which is confusing to us. Please [edit] the question, and take care when you are showing the data

Anyway, so you mean it should find the company which has a row with the earliest date from all the records, and then display all of that company's records..and then find the company with the next earliest date and display all their records? Not sure you can do that with SQL alone, although someone with more SQL knowledge may have a way

Sounds like you might want ORDER BY MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY storeid), id but very unclear, please explain the exact logic desired

There are transcription error in your desired result which isn't helping 1 |          1 | 2024-07-22 | storethree  should be 1 |          3| 2024-07-22 | storethree and  3 |          3 | 2024-07-01 | storeone  should be 1 |          1 | 2024-07-01 | storeone

Derive something else to order by based on the min date for every storeid eg
with cte as
(select storeid , min(date) dt from o group by storeid ),
cte1 as
(select storeid,rank() over (order by dt) sortorder from cte)
select * 
from  o
join cte1 on cte1.storeid = o.storeid
join s on s.id = cte1.storeid
order by cte1.sortorder,date;

https://dbfiddle.uk/-2M9B5ZZ
IS there a rule if 2 or more stores have the same min date?

Others have noted that your example data is incongruous so it's difficult to be sure what you're looking for. However based on the title of your post it sounds like you simply want to order by company first, and then get the oldest record per company. If that is the case you simply need to reverse your ORDER BY clause:
SELECT `o`.*,`s`.`name` FROM `orders` as o LEFT JOIN `stores` as s
    ON s.id = o.storeid ORDER BY s.id,o.date ASC;


No, that wouldn't produce the expected result - look at the order of the storeID in the expected output.

The expected output is chaos as the ID and name don't match up :) I assume that was an error, but you're right in order to more closely fit with that output you'd want to use ORDER BY s.name ASC,o.date ASC.

That's closer, but still not what was asked for (it would incorrectly put storeone first, for example). Look at the comment where the OP describes how it should use the dates (they really need to put that in the question, of course!)
